# Algorithm or Way to Determine Unfairness Pattern

Tags: algorithm

I want to know what kind of algorithm or way that I can do to detect a pattern in a game if someone is intentionally losing and using an alternate account to give their main account free wins.

I have a database with the records of each person that is categorized by days.
If a player is repeatedly winning against another player with an unfair amount of points or repeated amount of the same score (100 - 0) then the other player is intentionally losing.

**Example:**

Day 1

- 100 - 0 (Player_1 VS Player_2) (Player_1 Win)
- 100 - 0 (Player_1 VS Player_2) (Player_1 Win)
- 100 - 0 (Player_1 VS Player_2) (Player_1 Win)
- 100 - 0 (Player_1 VS Player_2) (Player_1 Win)
- 100 - 68 (Player_1 VS Player_3) (Player_1 Win)
- 100 - 68 (Player_1 VS Player_3) (Player_1 Win)

Day 2

- 100 - 0 (Player_1 VS Player_2) (Player_1 Win)
- 12 - 100 (Player_1 VS Player_3) (Player_3 Win)
- 100 - 0 (Player_1 VS Player_2) (Player_1 Win)

Day 3

- 100 - 0 (Player_1 VS Player_2) (Player_1 Win)
- 100 - 0 (Player_1 VS Player_2) (Player_1 Win)
- 52 - 100 (Player_1 VS Player_3) (Player_3 Win)

As we can see that Player_1 has been repeatedly winning against Player_2 with a perfect score of 100 - 0 so therefore Player_2 is intentionally losing against Player_1

I do not have any idea on how to start yet or what algorithm to use, if someone can point me in the right detection or give me any ideas then it is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Feature Extraction should be your first step, features to be considered in my opinion are:

- Total number of matches played by each player.
- Win/loss ratio for each player.
- Average score for each player.
- Frequency of specific match outcomes (e.g., 100-0 scores) involving a particular player.

  Then compute these features and any other features that you may think is important.

2. Now you should choose your anomaly detection method, There are two options in my opinion:

- Statistical methods such as z-score.
- Unsupervised machine learning algorithms like Isolation Forest or One-Class SVM.

  You should train the chosen model both based on fair games and intentional loose data set. If you could label some intentional it would be great for supervised learning.

3. Apply the trained model on your dataset and find the right thresholds for detecting anomaly.